# What is so "un-tanuki-like" about the name Kaisei?

Tags: the-eccentric-family

At the start of *Episode 9 - Daughter of the Ebisugawas: Kaisei* when Yasaburō is having a monologue about how he was arranged to marry Kaisei before her father called off the marriage after Yasaburō's father died, he says,

> By the way, my cousin's weird, un-tanuki-like name "Kaisei", was something my dad came up with.

What makes Kaisei's name "un-tanuki-like" in comparison to the other characters?

Comment: Note Kaisei is written (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eccentric_Family#Ebisugawa_family) and the family tree in the show given below) 海星, meaning “starfish”, not a common name in any species. (The kanji are “sea (umi)” and “star (hoshi)”.)

Answer (score 2):

[image: ep 9]

Common given names in Japan have a certain format since probably the Showa period.

Old fashioned male names go something like "*something*-*number*-郎". Kinkaku and Kinkaku's actual names are 呉二郎 and 呉三郎 (Kunijirou and Kunisaburo).

Female names usually go something like "*something*-子" or "*something*-美".

Kaisei breaks from this traditional name sense, which is why her name is un-tanuki-like.